# How to fix TypeError: 'file' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python

Im kinda new to python, and dont really understand my issue, really appreciate the help. Anyways, this is the line of coding.

```
def Banker(warrior):
    gold = open(chairs[warrior-1], "strength")
    return gold
```

This is the error i got.

```
line 22, in Banker
    gold = open(chairs[warrior-1], "strength")
TypeError: 'file' object is unsubscriptable
```

http://pastebin.com/1wMbaSYY

Comment: Can you post your entire code to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and edit your post to include the link, please?

Comment: Have you overridden the builtin `open` function?

Comment: Thanks james, i just did it, and im not sure Aesthete.

Comment: Could you update your answer to include in "plain English" - what you want to achieve?

Comment: Uhm, im not sure how to do that Jon, but i would just like to fix the error so my program will work.

Comment: Even if you fix this problem, `open(chairs[warrior-1], "strength")` is just going to raise a `ValueError`, because `"strength"` is not a valid file mode string. And, even after you get past that, `gold` is going to be a file object, which is almost certainly not what you want. What were you _trying_ to do with that line?

Comment: And that's why nobody can "fix the error so [your] program will work" without knowing what your program is supposed to do. We can fix the error so your program will do something arbitrary and probably nonsensical that isn't what you want, but how does that help you?

Comment: Oh, understood, well in essence the program is basically supposed to do this http://schools.tdsb.on.ca/danforthcti/ics4uu/BeatTheBank.html, i mean i wanna do this work on my own but im at a stump atm, :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like on your pastebin link, at line 19, in `toyota()` you have:

```
return chances, Tire, Km, Insurance, chairs
```

which returns all those values in a tuple (even without parentheses).  But, this is called in line 58:

```
chances, chairs, insurance, km, tire = toyota()
```

Which assigns the values from the returned tuple in order to the variables given on the left-hand side.  These tuples should be in the right order.  Here, you're using the value of `Tire` as `chairs`.

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem. Line 58 is what is causing you trouble. Here it is:

```
chances, chairs, insurance, km, tire = toyota()
```

Nothing wrong with that, but when we look at `toyota()`s return statement, there is an issue. Here is `toyota()`s return statement:

```
return chances, Tire, Km, Insurance, chairs
```

The problem arises from the fact that order matters when returning multiple values in Python, and the order in which you return and the order in which you assign does not match up.

Here you are returning the value of `Tire` and assigning it to the variable `chairs`. Later on, when you attempt to use `chairs` in the `Banker` function, you aren't working with the object you think you are.

```
gold = open(chairs[warrior-1], "strength")
```

Here, running `type(chairs)` will return `File`, not `list`, because `toyota()`s values were returned/assigned in the wrong order. `File`s can't be indexed and that is what causes your program to throw an error.